# Extract and sum totals for time period

Tags: python, pandas, datetime

I have a dataset of rainfall, with rainfall values being associated with a time (minute) and date on which rainfall occurred, if no rainfall occurred, nothing is logged. As such some days with large storms may have 100 readings, while some days will have none or only one or two. Example below:

```
D   M   Y       DAY     Hr  Min   Tot
2   3   2002    2419    5   49    0.2
2   3   2002    2419    5   53    0.4
2   3   2002    2419    5   57    0.2
2   3   2002    2419    6   8     0.6
3   3   2002    2420    3   11    0.2
3   3   2002    2420    3   13    0.2
3   3   2002    2420    23  3     0.8
3   3   2002    2420    23  4     0.4
3   3   2002    2420    23  29    0.6
4   3   2002    2421    19  7     0.2
4   3   2002    2421    19  8     0.2
4   3   2002    2421    19  9     0.2
4   3   2002    2421    19  10    0.2
('Tot' is rainfall total)
```

This dataset is about ten years long, and I need to translate this data into 10 minute, 1 hour and 3 hour totals for correlation with another variable. For example, I need to be able to extract the total rainfall that occurred in the ten minutes 3/3/2002 23:00:00-23:10:00, which comes to 1.2, and then also for the hour from 3/3/2002 23:00:00 which comes to 1.8, and so on.

As I understand it, this is not simply a group by and sum; it would be if I were extracting daily totals (which I have done already), but this seems more complicated than that. Are there any ideas out there as to how I might go about completing this task?

Many thanks for any thoughts and suggestions!

Comment: Could you please post the dataframe as an executable code example?

Comment: @Scotty1- You can  just copy it and do `df = pd.read_clipboard()`

Comment: Do you expect three dataframes/series as an output? One for 10 minutes, one for 1 hour, and one for 3 hour intervals?

Comment: @ScottBoston yes, this is what I am hoping for: three separate df for each size of time window, containing the rainfall totals and associated time stamps

Comment: @Brenlla nice. Didn't know of that feature. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the following to generate your three dataframes/series

#### Create a column with datetime dtype using `to_datetime`

```
df['date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Y'].astype(str)+'-'+df['M'].astype(str)+'-'+df['D'].astype(str)+' '+df['Hr'].astype(str)+':'+df['Min'].astype(str)+':00')
```

#### `resample` date with the intervals 10T, 1H and 3H with `sum`

```
df_10T = df.resample('10T', on='date')['Tot'].sum()
df_1H = df.resample('1H', on='date')['Tot'].sum()
df_3H = df.resample('3H', on='date')['Tot'].sum()
```

#### Display non-zero values of each series for checking.

#### 10 Minutes

```
df_10T[df_10T.ne(0)]
date
2002-03-02 05:40:00    0.2
2002-03-02 05:50:00    0.6
2002-03-02 06:00:00    0.6
2002-03-03 03:10:00    0.4
2002-03-03 23:00:00    1.2
2002-03-03 23:20:00    0.6
2002-03-04 19:00:00    0.6
2002-03-04 19:10:00    0.2
Name: Tot, dtype: float64
```

#### 1 hour

```
df_1H[df_1H.ne(0)]
date
2002-03-02 05:00:00    0.8
2002-03-02 06:00:00    0.6
2002-03-03 03:00:00    0.4
2002-03-03 23:00:00    1.8
2002-03-04 19:00:00    0.8
Name: Tot, dtype: float64
```

#### 3 hour

```
df_3H[df_3H.ne(0)]
date
2002-03-02 03:00:00    0.8
2002-03-02 06:00:00    0.6
2002-03-03 03:00:00    0.4
2002-03-03 21:00:00    1.8
2002-03-04 18:00:00    0.8
Name: Tot, dtype: float64
```

Comment: This is great, works absolutely as I was hoping, thank you so much

Answer (score 0):

First thing to do is to convert your dates to datetime objects. After that you can slice your dataframe with timedeltas.

```
import datetime
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df = pd.read_clipboard()

timestep = datetime.timedelta(hours=3)

dates = [datetime.datetime(Y, M, D, h, m) for Y, M, D, h, m in zip(df.Y, df.M, df.D, df.Hr, df.Min)]

df.index = dates

start = df.index.min()
steps = int(np.ceil((df.index.max() - start) / timestep))

bins = [start + i * timestep for i in range(steps)]
data = [df[bins[i]: bins[i+1]].Tot.sum() for i in range(int(steps-1))]

result = pd.DataFrame({"Total": data}, bins[:-1])
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks so much for your suggestion!